# Filtering data from Fusion table on map using more than one selection

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have Fusion Table data that I would like to map on a web page and give users the ability to filter the geopoints using selection menus based on data in columns.  I can do this using one column from the Fusion Table but I can't figure out how to do this using two or more columns. i.e./e.g. They can select/filter a column called 'Program' for entries labelled with 'GypsyMoth' and then further filter all these entries for 'TrapRteList' entries labelled 'NE'.

I have tried many, many ways of accomplishing this but so far no luck.  Below is my best attempt but it will only select data from TrapRteList.  How can get two column selections to update the map?  I'm not a programmer (obviously) and have been banging my head against a wall for awhile now.  None of the solutions I've found seem to work quite the way I want them to.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Tree Traps Map</title>

  <style>
    #map-canvas { width:1080px; height:768px; }
    .layer-wizard-search-label { font-family: sans-serif };
  </style>          

    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var pointTableID = '1EADJbmeOJj60i_jIMDPNwVt0SMYEwYsw8kuU3nwI';
        var pointColumn = 'GPSpoint';

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.637692, -113.422068),
          zoom: 10,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

// Initialize the points layer
        var pointsLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
          query: {
            select: pointColumn,
            from: pointTableID
          },
          map: map,
        styleId: 2,
        templateId: 2
        });

// -----------------------------------          

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('Program'),
            'change', function() {
              updateMap(pointsLayer, pointTableID, pointColumn);
        });

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('TrapRteList'),
            'change', function() {
              updateMap(pointsLayer, pointTableID, pointColumn);
        });     

      }

      // Update the query sent to the Fusion Table Layer based on
      // the user selection in the select menu
      function updateMap(pointsLayer, pointTableID, pointColumn) {
        var Program = document.getElementById('Program').value;
        if (Program) {
          pointsLayer.setOptions({
            query: {
              select: pointColumn,
              from: pointTableID,
              where: "Program = '" + Program + "'"
            }
          });
        } else {
          pointsLayer.setOptions({
            query: {
              select: pointColumn,
              from: pointTableID
            }
          });
        }

        var TrapRteList = document.getElementById('TrapRteList').value;
        if (TrapRteList) {
          pointsLayer.setOptions({
            query: {
              select: pointColumn,
              from: pointTableID,
              where: "TrapRteList = '" + TrapRteList + "'"
            }
          });
        } else {
          pointsLayer.setOptions({
            query: {
              select: pointColumn,
              from: pointTableID
            }
          });
        }       
      }   

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>

<p style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top:0.25em; margin-bottom:0.25em; width:20%; font-size:14pt; font-weight:bold;">Trapping Program</p>

  <label style="font-size:11pt; font-weight:bold;">Select trapping program: </label>
    <select id="Program">
        <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
        <option value="">(no value)</option>    
        <option value="Apanteles">Apanteles</option>
        <option value="AshBorer">Ash (or Lilac) Borer</option>
        <option value="EBB-Banded">Banded Elm Bark Beetle</option>
        <option value="EBB">Elm Bark Beetle</option>
        <option value="EmeraldAshBorer">Emerald Ash Borer</option>
        <option value="GypsyMoth">Gypsy Moth</option>
        <option value="InvasiveAliens">Invasive Alien Species</option>
        <option value="MountainPineBeetle">Mountain Pine Beetle</option>
        <option value="Sirix">Sirix</option>
        <option value="UglynestCaterpillar">Uglynest Caterpillar</option>
        <option value="Other:">Other Program</option>
    </select>

  <label style="font-size:11pt; font-weight:bold;">Select trap route: </label>
    <select id="TrapRteList">
        <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
        <option value="">(no value)</option>        
            <option value="NE">Northeast</option>
            <option value="NW">Northwest</option>
            <option value="SE">Southeast</option>
            <option value="SW">Southwest</option>
            <option value="OuterCommunity">Outer Community</option>
            <option value="Other:">Other</option>   
    </select>


    <div id="map-canvas"></div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be sufficient:

```
  function updateMap(pointsLayer, pointTableID, pointColumn) {
    var o={
            Program     : document.getElementById('Program').value,
            TrapRteList : document.getElementById('TrapRteList').value
          },where=[];

         for(var k in o){
           if(o[k]){
             where.push(k+"='"+o[k]+"'");
           }
         }

      pointsLayer.setOptions({
        query: {
          select: pointColumn,
          from: pointTableID,
          where: where.join(' and ')
        }
      });      
  }
```

Note: all options that shouldn't be used for filtering must have an value which evaluates to false , e.g. a empty string.